# How can we burn an iso image to hard disk? 

Tags: linux, iso-image

I know that:

1. An ISO image can be burned to a CD/DVD.
2. It can be mounted to any directory in the hard disk.
3. It can be burned to a CD, and then the contents be copied to the hard disk.

But can we actually put the contents of the ISO image on the hard disk (as in option 3 above) directly? (without burning it to a CD first)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it directly, for example, you could save a drive image into a iso and then recover it to the same hard disk using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Method 1 (GUI):

Double click the ISO image to open it. Drag all the files to another location on your hard drive.

Method 2 (command line):

Mount the ISO:

```
mount -o loop,ro /path/to/image.iso /mnt
cp -a /mnt/* /destination
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you kindly.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, But this only copy the files right? How can we actually **burn** the ISO into a USB hard drive?

Comment: @Pacerier He didn't ask about that, so I didn't address it.